# VSTS release, CMD webdeploy with variables inside Powershell quotation syntax

Tags: powershell, command-line, syntax, azure-devops

Apologies in advance if this is dumb and obvious. I have the following lines in a Powershell script executing as a release task in VSTS:

```
Write-Output "Stopping IIS..."  
CMD.exe /C "'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp='MyApp/MyAppPool',recycleMode='StopAppPool',computername=$privateIp,userName=$serverLogin,password=$serverPassword"
```

It produces the following output:

```
2017-10-07T15:07:33.3282985Z Stopping IIS...
2017-10-07T15:07:34.5470804Z ##[error]The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Per MS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc956689.aspx) this means one of the following characters is wrong: \ \ / [ ] : | < > + ; = . ? "

I can only assume it's my quote syntax because that's the only character used on this line. I know it's not the contents of any of the variables, because they are used elsewhere in the script with no problem (and don't contain any of the characters in question).

Help?

Comment: well can you just print your string and examine what gets constructed?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Err... how would I do that?

Comment: Create a variable to hold your command line string and then write that out to the host

Comment: That wasn't really a viable solution as assigning the line to a variable just puts the results in a variable and if I tried to wrap the whole thing as a string I had to alter the syntax a lot to make it work as a string, which ended up defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I figured out the answer:

```
CMD.exe /C "`"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe`" -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp='MySite/MySiteAppPool',recycleMode='StopAppPool',computername=$privateIp,userName=$serverLogin,password=$serverPassword"
```

Just a note for posterity, this is specifically a syntax that will work when you are attempting to stop/start/recycle an app pool on a server on the network, from a Powershell script, as a release task in VSTS, using msdeploy.